# How to achieve ripple animation on button without even clicking

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to show ripple on my button simply in the onCreate() of my activity. Of all the code I have scanned, ripple effect is only visible when button is pressed. Please guide me on how to show ripple by default without the button click.

Comment: Take a reference of this Link ---> http://www.tothenew.com/blog/ripple-effect-in-android/

and Make Changes:

Add the below 2 lines outside onTouch Event after initializing RippleDrawable and Button in OnCreate Method.

rippleDrawable.setHotspot(event.getX(), event.getY());
rippleDrawable.setColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)));

Comment: setHotspot() requires event.getX() & event.getY(). How to call 'event' in onCreate() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to click button but *programmatically*. Use `yourButton.performClick()` in your `onCreate` method and make sure when you do this do not run code that is handle on click event for your button for that you can use one `boolean` variable to check whether you are doing it programmatically or real action is perform

```
yourbutton clicklistener  {
if(isprogrammatic){
// dont do anything
 isprogrammatic = false
}
else{
// run your code
}
}
```

**OnCreate**

```
onCreate(Bundle..){ // your on create method

    //yes it is programmatic
    isprogrammatic = true;
    yourbutton.performClick();

    }
```

Comment: What if I want to handle click as well